# Select First Row of every MRN

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
SELECT   DISTINCT OH.MRN,OH.VISIT_NUMBER,OH.EVENT_TIME
FROM ONCOLOGY_HISTROY_MV OH
WHERE   OH.PROC='BC - Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
ORDER BY EVENT_TIME ASC
```

I'm trying to get the first visit for each MRN (Patient) in a particular PROC (which is Procedure)

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to use analytic functions:

```
SELECT MRN, VISIT_NUMBER, EVENT_TIME
FROM (SELECT OH.MRN, OH.VISIT_NUMBER, OH.EVENT_TIME,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OH.MRN ORDER BY OH.EVENT_TIME) AS SEQNUM
      FROM ONCOLOGY_HISTROY_MV OH
      WHERE OH.PROC = 'BC - Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
     ) OH
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
ORDER BY EVENT_TIME ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as this:

```
select mrn, min(visit_date) mindate
from oncology_history_mv
where proc = 'BC Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
group by mrn
```

If you need more details, make the above a derived table and join to it.

```
 select fields you need
 from oncology_history_mv onc join 
 (select mrn, min(visit_date) mindate
from oncology_history_mv
where proc = 'BC Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
group by mrn ) temp on onc.mrn = temp.mrn and vist_date = mindate
where proc = 'BC Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
```

This assumes that event_time does not include the date of the procedure, just the time of day.

Comment: In my experience, using analytics instead of a self join will be faster.

Answer (score -2):

it can be done as follow

```
SELECT  OH.MRN,,OH.EVENT_TIME
FROM ONCOLOGY_HISTROY_MV OH
WHERE   OH.PROC='BC - Heamatology-Oncology Appt'
ORDER BY EVENT_TIME AS
GROUP BY OH.MRN
HAVING min(OH.EVENT_TIME)
```

this will give you the first date when the MRN record was added which implies that it will be the first visit.

Comment: Minus 1 from me.  This will throw an error in oracle.